# how to convert list to IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have the following function in which should return an IEnumerable type?how do I convert list to IEnumerable? and return an empty IEnumerable?

```
public IEnumerable<SoftwareImageTestPlan> GetAssignedTestPlansForSPSI(int SoftwareProductID, int SoftwareImageID)
{
    var records = _entities.tblSoftwareImageTestPlans
        .Where(x => x.SoftwareProductID == SoftwareProductID && x.SoftwareImageID == SoftwareImageID)
        .ToList();

    if (records == null)
        return new List<SoftwareImageTestPlan>();
    else
        return records;
}
```

Error:

> Cannot implicty convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<....> to
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<.....>.An explicit conversion
>   exists(are you missing a cast?)

[image: error]

Comment: A `List<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>` so you shouldn't need to convert anything. Can you give us the full message? (with the ... replaced with the actual types).

Comment: Kenneth - I added a screenshot of the error

Comment: The namespaces are not the same, so they're not the same type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem is not in convertation of `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`. Becuase `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Your problem is that generic parameters are different. You are trying to convert `List<T1>` to `IEnumerable<T2>`. Where:

- T1 is `QlasrService.EntityFramework.tblSoftwareImageTestPlan`
- T2 is `QlasrService.Model.SchemaModels.LAP.SoftwareImageTestPlan`

Simplest solution will be mapping (either manual or [automatic](http://automapper.org/)). Automatic mapping is very easy. Add Automapper nuget package. Place this line somewhere on application start:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<tblSoftwareImageTestPlan, SoftwareImageTestPlan>());
```

And now your method will look like:

```
public IEnumerable<SoftwareImageTestPlan> GetAssignedTestPlansForSPSI(
   int SoftwareProductID, int SoftwareImageID)
{
    var testPlans = from tp in _entities.tblSoftwareImageTestPlans
                    where tp.SoftwareProductID == SoftwareProductID && tp.SoftwareImageID == SoftwareImageID
                    select tp;

    return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SoftwareImageTestPlan>>(testPlans);
}
```

NOTE: In your code either `records` cannot have `null` value, or you will have `NullReferenceException` at `ToList()` call. So `if..else` block is useless anyway.

Comment: Sergey - this gives an error `query body end with a select clause or a group clause` ,also what is the namespace to use `Mapper`

Comment: @kemosabee sorry, missed `select tp` line. Now its good. Mapper namespace is `using Automapper;`

Answer (score 5):

You're returning two different object types:

- tblSoftwareImageTestPlan - Which resides in your Entity Framework model
- SoftwareImageTestPlan - Which resides in your Qlasr Schema Models

Therefore when you state the following:

```
return records;
```

It will complain that the `records` object is not of type `SoftwareImageTestPlan`.  Therefore you need to convert `records` into a new `List<SoftwareImageTestPlan>` which you can achieve via a `LINQ projection`.

```
var records = (from entities in _entities.tblSoftwareImageTestPlans
               where entities.SoftwareProductID equals SoftwareProductID && entities.SoftwareImageID == SoftwareImageId
               select new SoftwareImageTestPlan
               {
                  SoftwareProductID = entities.SoftwareProductID,
                  SoftwareImageID = entities.SoftwareImageID
               }).ToList();
```

You can then use your original statement:

```
if (records == null)
    return new List<SoftwareImageTestPlan>();
else
    return records;
```

Comment: Darren - Can you provide a specific example for `ou need to convert records into a new List<SoftwareImageTestPlan> which you can achieve via a LINQ projection` ?

Comment: @kemosabee - I've updated my answer to include this.

Comment: Also note that in the end you can even do `return records ?? new List<SoftwareImageTestPlan>();`

Comment: Darren - Was your update just an example or actual syntax that works for you?I've difficutly to get to work

Comment: @kemosabee - try `entities in _entities.tblSoftwareImageTestPlans` rather than `=`. My answer contains the full snippet.

Comment: Darren - your solution works too but i found Sergey's answer to be more generic meaning I have figure out the right query for different operations where as Sergeys one can be reused

Answer (score 2):

The problem here isn't that you need to convert from `List` to `IEnumerable`.

The problem is that you're trying to convert from `List<tblSoftwareImageTestPlan>` to `IEnumerable<SoftwareImageTestPlan>`

Those are two completely different types, because of the type argument.

Possible solutions:

- Change the return type to `IEnumerable<tblSoftwareImageTestPlan>`
- Map the objects to `SoftwareImageTestPlan` by projecting the `tblSoftwareImageTestPlan` to a `SoftwareImageTestPlan`:

  ```
  public IEnumerable<SoftwareImageTestPlan> GetAssignedTestPlansForSPSI(int softwareProductID, int SoftwareImageID)
  {
      var records = _entities.tblSoftwareImageTestPlans
                             .Where(x => 
                               x.SoftwareProductID == SoftwareProductID && 
                               x.SoftwareImageID == SoftwareImageID)
                             .Select(x => new SoftwareTestPlan { 
                               Id = Id,  // example
                               ... do more mapping here  
                              })
                             .ToList();

      if (records == null)
          return new List<SoftwareImageTestPlan>();
      else
          return records;
  }
  ```