# C# cannot convert list to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable

I am quite new to C# and trying to figure out an issue in my code, but after doing some google i still I cannot figure out the problem here is my minimal code:

```
GetParamsResponse response = new GetParamsResponse()
List <Parameters> newParam = new List <Parameters> ();
response.stackParams.AddRange(newParam) // error appears here
```

I get an error:

> Argument 1: Cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.List<X.X.X.Parameters>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<X.X.X.Parameters>`

Comment: 'stackParams' may be of different type. Please have a look in to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516102/how-to-convert-list-to-ienumerable?rq=1

Comment: Maybe the type *inside* the List or IEnumerable doesn't match.

Comment: Your response is not complete. This is a "trivial" problem - so we need a complete repro example because on firs look it is ok, but then we miss the efinition of GetParamsResponse.

Comment: can you post class definition of `GetParamsResponse`? at least where it implement enumerables.

Comment: Hi i have edited my question please check again

Comment: And where is the definition of that GetParamsResponse type?

Comment: If `response.stackParams` is of type `IEnumerable` then you cannot add items to it.

Comment: Do you use reflection anywhere to load assemblies? If the namespaces are identical, chances are they types have been loaded into different contexts.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: For future reference, do not [delete and repost a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924554/c-sharp-convert-list-to-ienumerable). For one, it is better to work on improving the existing question, to preserve the entire chain of discussion and editing. But for another, closed/deleted posts may eventually lead to temporary restrictions on your ability to continue to post to the site. It's in your best interests to avoid doing that.

Comment: As for the updated question, you still have not provided a good [mcve], nor the actual error message. The `List<T>` class always implements `IEnumerable<T>`, whatever `T` is. So if you really were in fact using the same type `X.X.X.Parameters` for both the source list and the target `stackParams` object, you wouldn't get an error that looks like that. Please fix the question so that it's answerable.